# How to Authorise User login via twitter in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter-oauth

i am implementing login via `twitter` in my `ios` application.
i have already created twitter app on developer page.
i have twitter API key and secret.

Now i have added `AFOAuth2Manager` [CHECK HERE](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Manager) for `OAuth-Authorization` and 
`AFnetworking` framework.

and wrote a code while googling ,on button action as

```
      #import "AFOAuth2Manager.h"

    - (IBAction)loginWithTwitterAction:(id)sender
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"];
        AFOAuth2Client *oauthClient = [AFOAuth2Client clientWithBaseURL:url clientID:kClientID secret:kClientSecret];

        [oauthClient authenticateUsingOAuthWithURLString:@"/oauth/token" parameters:nil success:^(AFOAuthCredential *credential)
         {
             NSLog(@"I have a token! %@", credential.accessToken);
             [AFOAuthCredential storeCredential:credential withIdentifier:oauthClient.serviceProviderIdentifier];
         } failure:^(NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         }];
    }
```

Its not working please correct me.and i might have missed some other steps.

Comment: that's some nasty Twittering right there, why aren't you just using Fabric.io?

Comment: I'd also recommend using Fabric with TwitterKit, which enables you to smoothly integrate Twitter functionality in your app.

Comment: I agree...fabric is simple, smooth...and your integration takes no time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use Fabric.io as Larcerax is recommending you. When you install it you will be able to login with twitter really easy. I use these methods:

Login:

```
- (void)loginWithTwitter { 
    [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session,
                                              NSError *error) {
    if (session) {
      NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);
      [[NXTTwitterManager sharedInstance] requestTwtFollowersWithCursor:nil];
      [[NXTTwitterManager sharedInstance] requestTwtFollowingWithCursor:nil];
    } else {
      NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
  }];
}
```

Get Followers:

```
- (void)requestTwtFollowersWithCursor:(NSString *)nextCursor {
  NSString *statusesShowEndpoint = [NSString
      stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
                   @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?",
                   (nextCursor.length > 0)
                       ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cursor=%@&count=5000",
                                                    nextCursor]
                       : @"count=5000"];
  NSDictionary *params = @{ @"id" : [Twitter sharedInstance].session.userID };
  NSError *clientError;

  NSURLRequest *request = [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
      URLRequestWithMethod:@"GET"
                       URL:statusesShowEndpoint
                parameters:params
                     error:&clientError];

  if (request) {
    [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
        sendTwitterRequest:request
                completion:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data,
                         NSError *connectionError) {
                  if (data) {
                    NSError *jsonError;
                    NSDictionary *json =
                        [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                        options:0
                                                          error:&jsonError];
                    [self.followers addObjectsFromArray:json[@"ids"]];
                    if (![json[@"next_cursor_str"] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
                      [[NXTTwitterManager sharedInstance]
                          requestTwtFollowersWithCursor:
                              json[@"next_cursor_str"]];
                    } else {
                      [self matchFriends];
                    }
                  } else {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@", connectionError);
                    [self matchFriends];
                  }
                }];
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", clientError);
  }
}
```

Get Friends (following):

```
- (void)requestTwtFollowingWithCursor:(NSString *)nextCursor {
  NSString *statusesShowEndpoint = [NSString
          stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
                   @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json?",
                   (nextCursor.length > 0)
                       ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cursor=%@&count=5000",
                                                    nextCursor]
                       : @"count=5000"];
  NSDictionary *params = @{ @"id" : [Twitter sharedInstance].session.userID };
  NSError *clientError;

  NSURLRequest *request = [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
      URLRequestWithMethod:@"GET"
                       URL:statusesShowEndpoint
                parameters:params
                     error:&clientError];

  if (request) {
    [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
        sendTwitterRequest:request
                completion:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data,
                         NSError *connectionError) {
                  if (data) {
                    NSError *jsonError;
                    NSDictionary *json =
                        [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                        options:0
                                                          error:&jsonError];
                    [self.followings addObjectsFromArray:json[@"ids"]];
                    if (![json[@"next_cursor_str"] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
                      [[NXTTwitterManager sharedInstance]
                          requestTwtFollowingWithCursor:
                              json[@"next_cursor_str"]];
                    } else {
                      [self matchFriends];
                    }
                  } else {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@", connectionError);
                    [self matchFriends];
                  }
                }];
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", clientError);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi SonGoku68 . i saw that fabric  io and added its frame work also.
In the document it is mentioned that there are two types of authentication:
Guest and App Only Authentication , so i don't understand which one should be used in general.?

Comment: You need to use the one you need it. I don't know what are you going to do in your app. Here there is a list of things you can do with app authentication and what you can't. https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only

Comment: Also I am getting Error when i am making request to Get Followers as:
 Error: Error Domain=TwitterAPIErrorDomain Code=32 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" UserInfo=0x7fac70707240 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json?id=147170022, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401), NSLocalizedFailureReason=Twitter API error : Could not authenticate you. (code 32)

Comment: Do you have your consumerKey and consumerSecret added to your plist?

Comment: Yes it is added , this problem seems like authentication header is  missing,
Do we have to add in request header or twitter framework Automatically picks it up?

Comment: I saw that in my Fabric Dashboard the key is one which was default created by fabric for twitter.
and there is no option to change these keys and secret in dashbaord. do you have any idea how to edit it?

Comment: I see in your request "api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json?id=147170022" and if you read the documentation you can see the correct param is user_id. https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/list

Comment: Yes that is fine. i have checked with both id and user_id . same error
because i created new twitter app , but in Fabric dashboard the twitter key is default which was created by Fabric
and no option to change the app from Fabric dashboard